# Putting the words together

Tags: word, pattern

What's the relation between these words:

> mix
>
> audio
>
> duct
>
> measure
>
> electric
>
> magnetic
>
> deck

(This one isn't very difficult for my first attempt of a word puzzle.)

Since it's been solved, I'll add others that I can think of just for a completed list:

> Scotch
>
> grip
>
>  recorder

Comment: Ignoring the many kinds of adhesive tape, here are some more for the list: red, off, cassette, video, punch, caution, drive, audition, sex, gun, and everything found on [this list](http://www.onelook.com/?w=**tape**&ls=a)

Comment: Technically it should be 'Duct' not 'Duck' unless you are referring to the specific brand name of that product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> All of the words can be preceded or followed by the word **tape** to create another word/phrase:
> mix tape
> duck tape
> audio tape
> tape measure
> electric tape
> magnetic tape
> deck tape / tape deck

Comment: To me, some of the words sound better when preceded by tape: tape measure, tape deck

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking deck tape like you'd use for a skateboard - you're right about the tape measure though. I was thinking along the lines of measuring tape, I assumed it was a difference in regional expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> tape. They can all be followed by -tape to form a word.